# turning exit-on-suspend off in phonegap application on Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I wrote an application using Phonegap on Android and ran it directly from Eclipse on my mobile device (Android). exit on suspend config was `true`.

Now I want to update the application and I'm not able to do that since each time I run the application from Eclipse (to be ran on my device) I get the old version since each time I exit the application it gets suspended and then resumed when launched again.

The update is critical as there are some database information that I need and I'm not able to use the code I wrote to get the information needed since the application is not getting updated on the mobile (it's resuming all the time).

What can be done to force an update to the application without losing the database (SQLite)? I changed the `config.xml` and turned off exit-on-suspend but it's not doing anything since Cordova is always detecting the previous (suspended) version.

I tried killing the running applications, restarting both the mobile phone and eclipse and adb but that didn't work out.

Is it possible to uninstall the application and install it again without losing the database? If not, how do I updated the application?

Thank you.

EDIT: Typos.

Comment: I do not understand your question. When your app is being updated by Eclipse, it gets suspended and exit nonetheless. I can confirm that updating an app like this through Eclipse won't delete data that comes with the app. So if you develop a new version and update the one on your test device, you will see that the same data is still there. But it is possible that I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: Uninstalling an app will lose the local data (sqlite). But running the updated app from eclipse will update your mobile device's app. Do you change the codes elsewhere and just use the eclipse as a launching tool? If so, you need to refresh your eclipse project (in the project view) so it will load latest codes.

Answer (score -1):

I think the new value (per Cordova 3.3) may be:

`<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>`.

Answer (score -1):

This is coming really, really late but it might help others...

Just simply Cleaning the project before Running the application by doing the following;

1. Go to Project Menu
2. Then click on Clean
3. Select the current project you are working on and click on Ok

That will clean you project but will not uninstall it and your new updates will be implemented.

Hope it helps, cheers!!!